# Setting up rabbitMQ on docker with python

Tags: python, docker, localhost, rabbitmq, microservices

I am fairly new to docker and I am learning about rabbitMQ. So far I have been able to run rabbitMQ, in the form of the python libary pika, on my ubuntu vm. This worked with no problems at all but I have now put it onto a small app in docker and does not work.

The problem seems to be in the set up and it all ways fails this line of code:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=HOST, port=80, credentials=credentials))
```

The Variables being imported:

```
USER = "test"
PASS = "testpass1"
HOST = "dockerhost"
```

The file:

```
import pika
from settings import USER, PASS, HOST

def send(message):

    message = str(message)
    print 'trying: credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username=USER, password=PASS)'
    try:
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username=USER, password=PASS)
    except Exception:
        print 'Failed'
        print str(Exception)
        return 'Failed on: credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username=USER, password=PASS) \n' + str(Exception.message)

    print 'trying: connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=HOST, port=80, credentials=credentials))'
    try:
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host=HOST, port=80, credentials=credentials))
    except Exception:
        print 'Failed'
        print str(Exception)
        return 'Failed on: connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=HOST, port=80, credentials=credentials)) \n' + str(Exception.message)

    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body=message)
    connection.close()

    return "Message Sent"
```

Within this code it always fails on the line:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=HOST, port=80, credentials=credentials))
```

And finally the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Will Mayger
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tar git curl nano wget dialog net-tools build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python python-dev python-distribute python-pip
RUN git clone https://github.com/CanopyCloud/microservice-python
RUN pip install -r /microservice-python/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /microservice-python/
CMD sudo rabbitmqctl add_user test testpass1
CMD sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost myvhost
CMD sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost test ".*" ".*" ".*"
CMD sudo rabbitmq-server

CMD python /microservice-python/server.py
```

For any additional information all the files are located on:
https://github.com/CanopyCloud/microservice-python

Answer (score 2):

Your `Dockerfile` is not correct.

Try this instead:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Will Mayger
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y tar git curl nano wget dialog net-tools build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y python python-dev python-distribute python-pip
RUN git clone https://github.com/CanopyCloud/microservice-python
RUN pip install -r /microservice-python/requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /microservice-python/
RUN sudo rabbitmqctl add_user test testpass1
RUN sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost myvhost
RUN sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost test ".*" ".*" ".*"
RUN sudo rabbitmq-server

CMD python /microservice-python/server.py
```

The reason it isn't/wasn't correct was because you were defning multiple `CMD`(s) in your `Dockerfile`. I'm pretty sure docker will only set the last command in the resulting image and `CMD` does not "run" things as part of the image build process; `RUN` does.

`CMD` sets up the "command" that the image runs as part of `docker run <image>`

---

Also you seem to have combined RabbitMQ and your Python app into the one Docker Image/Container; which isn't really the *best* thing to do here.

You *should* instead split this out into two images.

- A RabbitMQ Image/Container
- Your App Image/Container

And use "Docker Links" via `docker run --link` to link the containers together.

---

You *can* build an Image for your Python APp quite easily by using something like this as a separate `Dockerfile` for your Python App:

```
FROM python:2.7-onbuild

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD server.py /app

WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python", "./server.py"]
```